# INSERT in a WHILE LOOP Not Inserting into Database

Tags: mysql, while-loop, sql-insert

I have a SELECT statement, WHILE statement and an INSERT:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT winner, time, course, market, twitter_pubstatus
FROM combo 
WHERE twitter_pubstatus = 0 AND market = '$win' GROUP BY winner");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
$winner = $row['winner'];
$time = $row['time'];
$course = $row['course'];

$message = "$winner won the $time at $course.  You are a winner! #GetIn";

$query = "INSERT INTO messageTable (MESSAGE) VALUES($message)or die(mysql_error())";

}
```

It runs through with no errors.  There should be 12 rows that get inserted into the database.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing $query = "INSERT INTO messageTable (MESSAGE) VALUES($message)or die(mysql_error())"; to $query = "INSERT INTO messageTable (MESSAGE) VALUES('$message')or die(mysql_error())";

Notice the single quotes in '$message'

Comment: in addition u are not executing the insert query .. and mixing mysql with mysqli `mysql_error()`

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `$query = "INSERT INTO messageTable (MESSAGE) VALUES($message)or die(mysql_error())";` 
to
 `$query = "INSERT INTO messageTable (MESSAGE) VALUES('$message')or die(mysql_error())";`

Notice the single quotes in `'$message'`

And $query is just a string so execute the query
`$result=mysqli_query($query)`

And then check if query executed by doing this
`if(!$result) die(mysqli_error());`